# Does multicollinearity cause type I errors?

Tags: correlation, multicollinearity, validation, type-i-and-ii-errors

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Consequences_of_multicollinearity) on multicollinearity,

> One of the features of multicollinearity is that the standard errors of the affected coefficients tend to be large. In that case, the test of the hypothesis that the coefficient is equal to zero may lead to a failure to reject a false null hypothesis of no effect of the explanator, a **type II error**.

I understand it as "multicollinearity turns your regression underpowerful by increasing coefficients variance", am I right?

Does this mean that it won't increase type I error?

NB: context is a Cox PH regression with 2 correlated explaining variables, with significant results which I'd like to be sure of. Modelization purpose is 100% inference, not prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multicollinearity makes the estimated slopes vary more widely from one sample to the next.  The ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator handles this correctly by having an estimated standard error that matches the long run sample to sample variability.  That is, it is larger than it would have been had the variables been orthogonal.

The result of multicollinearity is that you will have lower power for collinear variables.  However, it does not induce bias (the sampling distributions are still centered on the true values).  In addition (and specific to this question), *it does not affect the type I error rate for variables for which the null holds*.

An easy way to work through questions like this is to run simulations.  The tricky part is that you want to find a way to structure the simulation such that other aspects are held constant so that comparisons will be valid.  What I do below is generate datasets with 4 regressors, two of which ($x_1$ and $x_2$) are collinear with each other (they have ${\rm VIFs} \approx 10$), but which are orthogonal with two others ($x_3$ and $x_4$) that are also orthogonal with each other.  All variables are standardized to have the same SD.  For comparisons, one collinear variable and one orthogonal variable have true, and equal, effects, and the other collinear and orthogonal variables are true nulls.  Then we can compare their sampling distributions, and their power and type I error rates.  Below the simulation, I examine the last generated dataset to show that the criteria were met.  The results show that multicollinearity only increases the variances of the sampling distributions, and thereby decreases power, but has no effect on bias or type I error rates.  The simulation is coded in R, but is intended to be as close to pseudocode / self-explanatory as possible for those who do not use R.

```r
##### preliminaries
library(MASS)
N   = 100    # on each iteration, I will generate 100 data
B   = 10000  # I will run the simulation 10k times
est = matrix(NA, nrow=B, ncol=4)  # these will store the results
SE  = matrix(NA, nrow=B, ncol=4)
p   = matrix(NA, nrow=B, ncol=4)

##### simulation
set.seed(7244)  # this makes the simulation exactly reproducible
for(i in 1:B){
  ## here I generate multivariate normal regressors, w/ x1 & x2 collinear
  X  = mvrnorm(N, mu=c(0,0,0,0), Sigma=rbind(c(1.0, .95, 0.0, 0.0),
                                             c(.95, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                             c(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
                                             c(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) ))
  x1 = scale(X[,1])  # scale ensures all variables will have mean=0, & SD=1
  x2 = scale(X[,2])
             # by residualizing, I ensure x3 & x4 are prefectly orthogonal
  x3 = scale(resid(lm(X[,3]~X[,1]+X[,2]+X[,4])))  
  x4 = scale(resid(lm(X[,4]~X[,1]+X[,2]+x3)))
  ## there is a real effect of x1 & x3 (w/ identical slopes), 
  ##  but the null holds for x2 & x4
  y  = 0 + 1*x1 + 0*x2 + 1*x3 + 0*x4 + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=1)
  sm = summary(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4))   # fitting a multiple regression model
  ## storing the output
  est[i,] = sm$coefficients[2:5,1]  # estimated slopes
  SE[i,]  = sm$coefficients[2:5,2]  # standard errors
  p[i,]   = sm$coefficients[2:5,4]  # p-values
}

##### examining the last generated dataset
d = data.frame(y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, x4=x4)
round(sapply(d[,2:5], mean), digits=3)  # the regressor means really are 0
# x1 x2 x3 x4 
#  0  0  0  0 
round(sapply(d[,2:5], sd), digits=3)    # the regressor SDs really are 1
# x1 x2 x3 x4 
#  1  1  1  1 
round(cor(d[,2:5]), digits=3)           # x1 & x2 really are collinear &
#       x1    x2 x3 x4                  # x3 & x4 really are orthogonal
# x1 1.000 0.958  0  0
# x2 0.958 1.000  0  0
# x3 0.000 0.000  1  0
# x4 0.000 0.000  0  1

##### results of the simulation
## the sampling distributions are unbiased
round(apply(est,   2, mean), digits=3)  # [1] 1.001 0.000 1.000 0.000
## their variances differ, the collinear varibles vary 10X more
round(apply(SE**2, 2, mean), digits=3)  # [1] 0.107 0.107 0.010 0.010
## the power of x1 (collinear, but real) is lower than x3 (orthogonal, but real),
##  but, both x3 & x4 (collinear & not, but true nulls) have 'power' / type I 
##  error rates equal to alpha
round(apply(p<.05, 2, mean), digits=3)  # [1] 0.860 0.048 1.000 0.049
```

Comment: Incredible answer ! I've been wanting to make small simulations like this for ages, thanks a lot for the class !

Answer (score 3):

It does increase the type II error because:

The test statistic t for coefficient $b$ is equal to $ b/s_b $, the parameter estimate divided by its standard deviation. This value follows a t distribution. The type II error increases as $s_b$ increases because the quantity $ b/s_b $ is getting smaller thus more difficult to reject the null hypothesis of having a zero estimate for the same significance level.

The probability of a type I error decreases because it gets more difficult to reject the null hypothesis. In other words you are overconfident about H0 as you rarely reject and that shrinks the error of rejecting it thus minimizing a type I error by definition.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. So a significant result in a multicollinear model is actually "better" since it was harder to reject H0 ?

Comment: I would not go that far. You are falsely claiming that coefficients are zero to achieve a lower type I error. Your model is worse than what it appears.

Comment: I don't understand this time. If the result is significant, I'm rather claiming that coefficients are different from zero, no ?

Comment: The idea of "significant" is [becoming passé](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108#.XAwqSRBRf0o).

Comment: @FrankHarrell I wish it were, but most editors still want their p-values... Very interesting article though !

Comment: The probability of type I error does not decrease. I finally got around to posting an answer. The simulation demonstrates this.